# Mail through sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have the table "Customer"

It contains the fields - CustomerID,Email and ExpiryDate.

eg:

```
CustomerID         Email               ExpiryDate

1                  aji@gmail.com       19/11/2010

2                  john@yahoo.com      18/11/2010 

3                  Joseph@gmail.com    19/11/2010
```

I have to send an alert mail to all customers email ids whose expirydate is today.

How can I do it in sql 2000?

Answer (score 1):

Install Sql Mail: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=363

Answer (score 0):

- [SQL mail](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263556), requires a MAPI client, uses xp_sendmail
- Use the extended stored proc [xp_smtp_sendmail](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=&q=xm_smtp_sendmail) for SMTP (not sure if supported now, YMMV)
- Last resort: [use sp_OA% and cdosys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312839)

Or upgrade